# Mantener color de celda activa en QTableView

Tags: qt

Partimos de una tabla muy simple para el ejemplo, a la cual le pongo un fondo de color a la primera columna mediante un delegado.

**widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class TablaColor;

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    TablaColor* mitabla;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include "./tablacolor.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mitabla =  new TablaColor(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**tablacolor.h**

```
#ifndef TABLACOLOR_H
#define TABLACOLOR_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTableView>

class TablaColor : public QTableView
{
public:
    TablaColor(QWidget *parent = nullptr);    
};

#endif // TABLACOLOR_H
```

**tablacolor.cpp**

```
#include "tablacolor.h"
#include "modelotablacolor.h"
#include "delegadotablacolor.h"

TablaColor::TablaColor(QWidget *parent) : QTableView(parent)
{
    setModel(new ModeloTablaColor);
    setItemDelegateForColumn(0,new DelegadoTablaColor);
}
```

**modelotablacolor.h**

```
    #ifndef MODELOTABLACOLOR_H
    #define MODELOTABLACOLOR_H

    #include <QAbstractTableModel>

    class ModeloTablaColor : public QAbstractTableModel
    {
    public:
        ModeloTablaColor(QObject *parent = nullptr);
        QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
        bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole);
        int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
        int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    };

    #endif // MODELOTABLACOLOR_H
```

**modelotablacolor.cpp**

```
#include "modelotablacolor.h"

ModeloTablaColor::ModeloTablaColor(QObject *parent):QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{

}

QVariant ModeloTablaColor::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(role)
    if (index.isValid())
    {
        return "dato";
    }
    return QVariant();
}

bool ModeloTablaColor::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    Q_UNUSED(role)
    Q_UNUSED(value)
    if (index.isValid())
    {
        return  true;
    }
    return  false;
}

int ModeloTablaColor::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED (parent)
    return 4;
}

int ModeloTablaColor::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED (parent)
    return 2;
}
```

**delegadotablacolor.h**

```
#ifndef DELEGADOTABLACOLOR_H
#define DELEGADOTABLACOLOR_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>


class DelegadoTablaColor : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    DelegadoTablaColor(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
};

#endif // DELEGADOTABLACOLOR_H
```

**delegadotablacolor.cpp**

```
#include <QPainter>
#include "./delegadotablacolor.h"

DelegadoTablaColor::DelegadoTablaColor(QObject *parent): QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{

}

void DelegadoTablaColor::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (index.isValid())
    {
    painter->setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt::green)));
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::gray)));
    painter->drawRect(option.rect);
    painter->setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt::darkYellow)));
    painter->drawText(option.rect, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter,index.data().toString());
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }

}

QSize DelegadoTablaColor::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Q_UNUSED (option)
    Q_UNUSED (index)
    return QSize();
}
```

El problema que tengo es que usando delegados de esta forma, tal y como está implementada ahora la función `paint`, cuando me posiciono sobre una celda no se ve el color resaltado.
Es decir, si el índice es válido, no llamo a la versión `paint()` de la clase base.

Si llamo en todo momento a la clase base (estoy quitando el `else`):

```
void DelegadoTablaColor::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (index.isValid())
    {
    painter->setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt::green)));
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt::cyan)));
    painter->drawRect(option.rect);
    painter->setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt::magenta)));
    painter->drawText(option.rect, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter,index.data().toString());
    }
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}
```

Se me resalta la celda activa, pero a cambio la función base me vuelve a renderizar el contenido de la tabla. (el dato sale dos veces, cada uno representado con su propia versión de `paint()`)

Entonces la pregunta es....¿cómo hay que hacer para que se mantenga el color resaltado cuando se pasa por la celda sin duplicar la representación del dato?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo se va a cambiar las propiedades que se usan para hacer el pintado, es decir color de texto, color de fondo, alineamiento de texto que estan asociados a un rol pero no se quiere usar un modelo para ello entonces lo más sencillo es *override* el metodo initStyleOption y dibujar encima el borde verde:

```cpp
#ifndef DELEGADOTABLACOLOR_H
#define DELEGADOTABLACOLOR_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class DelegadoTablaColor : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
protected:
    void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
};

#endif // DELEGADOTABLACOLOR_H
```

```cpp
#include "delegadotablacolor.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QPalette>

void DelegadoTablaColor::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    if(index.isValid()){
        QPen pen((QColor(Qt::green)));
        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->drawRect(option.rect.adjusted(pen.width(), pen.width(), -pen.width(), -pen.width()));
    }
}

void DelegadoTablaColor::initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
    option->backgroundBrush = QBrush(QColor(Qt::gray));
    option->palette.setBrush(QPalette::Text, QBrush(QColor(Qt::darkYellow)));
    option->displayAlignment = Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter;
}
```

Comment: Solo una duda. ¿Qué quiere decir lo de usar "un modelo para ello"? (Bueno, no usarlo en este caso). Gracias!

Comment: @user3733164 El color de fondo, color de texto y alineamiento estan asociados a los roles Qt::BackgroundRole, Qt::BackgroundRole y Qt::TextAlignmentRole, respectivamente, por lo que si devuelves esos valores en el metodo data del modelo entonces no tendras que usar un delegado (salvo para el borde verde)